# Why can't I add data with an AffinityKey into an Apache Ignite cache?

Tags: c#, .net, ignite, gridgain

I am trying to use a GridGain Community on-prem cluster to evaluate the product for use at scale.

I am trying to use it with the .Net thin client. I wanted to use a combination of the Key-Value API and the SQL API to get the best performance.

As documented in the code below, I get a strange exception when trying to insert data when I have an AffinityKey defined. I have tried numerous combinations of attributes and schema definitions and I get unintuitive behaviour in a a lot of cases. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

```
using Apache.Ignite.Core;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.Affinity;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.Configuration;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Cache.Query;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Client;
using Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.Cache;

public record PERSONKEY(
    [property:AffinityKeyMapped] [property: QuerySqlField(NotNull = true)] long COMPANYID, 
    [property: QuerySqlField(NotNull = true)] long PERSONID);

public record PERSONVALUE(
    [property: QuerySqlField(NotNull = true)] string FIRSTNAME, 
    [property: QuerySqlField(NotNull = true)] string LASTNAME);

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cfg = new IgniteClientConfiguration
        {
            Endpoints = new[] {"10.7.116.49:10800"},
        };
        using var client = Ignition.StartClient(cfg);

        var schemaBuilder = client.GetOrCreateCache<int, int>(new CacheClientConfiguration
        {
            Name = "RR", SqlSchema = "PUBLIC"
        });

        schemaBuilder.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
            $@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PERSON (
                COMPANYID BIGINT NOT NULL,
                PERSONID BIGINT NOT NULL,
                FIRSTNAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                LASTNAME VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY(COMPANYID, PERSONID)
            ) WITH ""TEMPLATE=PARTITIONED,BACKUPS=1,AFFINITY_KEY=COMPANYID,CACHE_NAME=PERSON,
                     KEY_TYPE={typeof(PERSONKEY).FullName},VALUE_TYPE={typeof(PERSONVALUE).FullName}"""
        ) { Schema = "PUBLIC" }).GetAll();
        
        var cache = client.GetCache<PERSONKEY, PERSONVALUE>("PERSON");
        
        var key = new PERSONKEY(1, 2);
        var value = new PERSONVALUE("JOHN", "SMITH");
        
        // Throws an exception
        // Apache.Ignite.Core.Common.IgniteException: Affinity keys are not supported.
        // Object 'PERSONKEY { COMPANYID = 1, PERSONID = 2 }' has an affinity key.
        cache.Put(key, value);
        
        // Does not throw an exception
        cache.PutAll(new[]{KeyValuePair.Create(key, value)});
        
        var people = cache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE COMPANYID = ?", key.COMPANYID)).GetAll();
        // Correctly prints "1 2 JOHN SMITH"
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", people.Select(p => $"{p[0]} {p[1]} {p[2]} {p[3]}")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug, I've created a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-19359

**Workaround:** disable [partition awareness](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/thin-clients/dotnet-thin-client#partition_awareness) in `IgniteClientConfiguration`:

```cs
var cfg = new IgniteClientConfiguration
{
    EnablePartitionAwareness = false,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I'm assuming this will have an impact on performance due to extra network hops. Would you say this is still the optimal route? Or would it make sense to do all writes via the SQL API also?

Comment: SQL API is not partition aware and can also cause extra hops. Key/Value API is usually more efficient than SQL for individual entry operations (no need to parse query, etc).